# Creating an XDocument properly

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to create an xml file with C# and I keep getting this error:

**{"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."}**

I am following a guide I found online but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The guide I am following is located here: http://luka.manojlovic.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/05-Code.png

Here is my code:

```
var xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Data"),
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[0].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", runbookId)), //RunbookID
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[1].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.JobTitle)), //Title
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[2].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.UserName)),//Username
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[3].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.LastName)), //Lastname
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[4].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetManager(employee))), //Manager
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[5].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", "")),  //Phone
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[6].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.Initials)),//GUI Initials
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[7].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.EmployeeNumber)), //Employee #
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[8].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetCompany(employee))), //Company
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[9].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", "")), //Employee Security
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[10].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetDepartment(employee))), //Department
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[11].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.Location)), //Office
                new XElement("Parameter",
                    new XElement("ID", parameters[12].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.FirstName)) //First Name

             );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create an `XDocument` with multiple [root elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  You can't do that because the XML standard disallows it.  You probably meant to make the `"Parameter"` elements children of `Data`:

```
        var xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Data",
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[0].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", runbookId)), //RunbookID
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[1].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.JobTitle)), //Title
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[2].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.UserName)),//Username
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[3].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.LastName)), //Lastname
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[4].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetManager(employee))), //Manager
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[5].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", "")),  //Phone
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[6].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.Initials)),//GUI Initials
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[7].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.EmployeeNumber)), //Employee #
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[8].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetCompany(employee))), //Company
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[9].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", "")), //Employee Security
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[10].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", GetDepartment(employee))), //Department
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[11].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.Location)), //Office
                        new XElement("Parameter",
                            new XElement("ID", parameters[12].Id.ToString("B")), new XElement("Value", employee.FirstName)) //First Name
                            )
                     );
```