# Create dynamic xml using xelement in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I want to create xml using `XElement` as you can see:

```
XDocument RejectedXmlList = new XDocument
(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null)
);
int RejectCounter = 0;

foreach (Parameter Myparameter in Parameters)
{
    if (true)
    {
        XElement xelement = new XElement(Myparameter.ParameterName, CurrentData.ToString());
        RejectedXmlList.Add(xelement);
    }
}
```

As you can see if the condition is OK the parameter should be added to `RejectedXmlList` but instead I get this exception:

```
This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
```

Of note, the first parameter is added successfully.  Only when the second one is added do I get the exception.

The expected result should be like this:

```
<co>2</co>
<o2>2</o2>
....
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Creating an XDocument properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30792354/3744182) - you're trying to create an XML document with multiple [root elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), which is not allowed by the XML standard.

Comment: @dbc that is not my answer.i want to create the xml using foreach

Comment: It's the same problem.  You must add a single root element to your `XDocument`.  Then you can add multiple child elements for each `Parameter` to that root element.

Comment: I added this line RejectedXmlList.Root.Add("Rejectedparameters"); in the first line of my code ,but it returns null reference error .

Comment: Well of course -- you need to create the `RejectedXmlList.Root` element.  You only created the `XDocument`, not its root.

Comment: @dbc could you please give me in details ?Thank you

Comment: @dbc thank you it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create an `XDocument` with multiple [root elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), one for each `Parameter` in `Parameters`  You can't do that because the [XML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#dt-root) disallows it:

> There is **exactly one** element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.

The LINQ to XML API enforces this constraint, throwing the exception you see when you try to add a second root element to the document.

Instead, add a root element, e.g. `<Rejectedparameters>`, then add your `xelement` children to it:

```
// Allocate the XDocument and add an XML declaration.  
XDocument RejectedXmlList = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

// At this point RejectedXmlList.Root is still null, so add a unique root element.
RejectedXmlList.Add(new XElement("Rejectedparameters"));

// Add elements for each Parameter to the root element
foreach (Parameter Myparameter in Parameters)
{
    if (true)
    {
        XElement xelement = new XElement(Myparameter.ParameterName, CurrentData.ToString());
        RejectedXmlList.Root.Add(xelement);
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wcd3oW).