# Create an XDocument from specific elements of a larger XML using XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a very large XML file (> 100MB) and I want to only look at a few, small elements within it via Linq to XML.

I know there are many ways to do this, but I want to keep this in memory to use in different places throughout my program, so, what I'm looking to do is to traverse through this document once with an `XMLReader` and create my own `XDocument` variable with only those elements I'll need to look at, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Here's the basics of the code I have so far:

```
XDocument parsedXml = new XDocument();

using (var rdr = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
{
    rdr.MoveToContent();
    rdr.Read();

    while (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        switch (rdr.Name)
        {
            case "Node1":
            case "Node2":
            case "Node3":
                XElement newNode = XElement.Load(rdr.ReadSubtree());
                parsedXml.Add(newNode);
                rdr.Read();
                break;
            default:
                rdr.Skip();
                break;
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

It works for the first element I add, but then I get an error - `This operation would create an incorrectly structured document` when I try and add any other nodes.

What is the best way to accomplish this??

Thanks!!

Comment: If your result is a new Xml/XDocument, I'd go for Xslt but that's just personal preference and maybe a little improved performance.

Comment: The problem, @Filburt, is that then I'm loading the whole document into memory. This method streams it via the `XMLReader` and only pulls the relevant nodes into memory and, so, doesn't blow up the resources.

Comment: Xslt can act on a StreamReader just as well and I wouldn't expect it to consume more resources than XmlTextReader.

Comment: @Filburt, I'm not sure I understand - I need my final value to be an XDocument, are you saying you could create it using an XSLT that wouldn't increase the memory consumption over an XMLReader? Could you show me how? - I always thought the XSLT loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this as my solution - If there's a better way, please let me know / post up your solutions, but, if not, I hope this helps others....

```
XDocument parsedXml = new XDocument();
parsedXml.AddFirst(new XElement("root"));

using (var rdr = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
{
    rdr.MoveToContent();
    rdr.Read();

    while (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        switch (rdr.Name)
        {
            case "Node1":
            case "Node2":
            case "Node3":
                XElement newNode = XElement.Load(rdr.ReadSubtree());
                parsedXml.Root.Add(newNode);
                rdr.Read();
                break;
            default:
                rdr.Skip();
                break;
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

Basically, creating a root node:

```
parsedXml.AddFirst(new XElement("root"));
```

and then adding to it specifically:

```
parsedXml.Root.Add(newNode);
```

Hope this helps others too!!

Comment: That's the correct solution -- a valid XML file must contain one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), and the LINQ-to-XML API enforces this requirement.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44993286/3744182) for a very similar question.

Comment: Also, you might consider using [`XNode.ReadFrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you use `ReadSubtree()` you must close or dispose the subtree reader before advancing the outer reader as explained [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: Following @dbc's link regarding `XNode.ReadFrom()` I found [How to: Perform Streaming Transform of Large XML Documents (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-perform-streaming-transform-of-large-xml-documents) so you may want consider this as the recommended solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Filburt, it pretty much became what I implemented,although your idea got me looking at Saxon as a possible streaming XSLT solution.... It's so different from what I know, though, but seems promising!!
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Using Xslt would be as simple as:

```
XDocument parsedXml = new XDocument();

using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
{
    using (var xw = parsedXml.CreateWriter())
    {
        XslCompiledTransform ct = new XslCompiledTransform();
        ct.Load(xsltFileName);
        ct.Transform(fileName, xw);
    }
}
```

I tried to do some quick profiling but I don't have a suitable source Xml at hand so you may want to give it a try with your real data.

While your likely simplified example surely doesn't require sophisticated transformations, Xslt wins quickly over `switch-case` or `if`s needed for real world data.

One more thing worth noting is using `XmlReader.Create()` rather than `XmlTextReader()` as mentioned in [Why is my new XmlTextReader(stream) reading in many megabytes into memory rather than streaming properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32940927/205233)

Comment: Filburt, I'm looking online and seeing that most people are saying that it loads the whole DOM into memory - such as here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46e19100-9860-46ff-ade7-6a59fc49e011/transforming-large-xml-files-with-xslcompiledtransform?forum=xmlandnetfx
Is that not the case? Because I agree with you that this would be a really neat way to implement this!